# Can't install SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, installation, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to install SQLAlchemy for a project.  I've tried 3 different computers running Windows 7, Vista, and 7 with identical python32 installations.  My first issue was an inability to execute easy_install on any of these computers for different reasons. Next, running the included setup.py script didn't work, even after running distribute_setup.py and running the script from the command prompt as "python setup.py install". Finally, trying to manually run the sa2to3.py script manually on the sqlalchemy folder did not work; it spat out an error message about not being able to find the folder, even when given an absolute path.

Comment: wellcome to SO. `Didn't work` doesn't give a clear view of what is happening. Please, be more precise, give details of what you did and the actual, full errors or traceback you got. Installing SQLAlchemy in win 7 does not need any special permit, Just with `python setup.py install`. Take into account that in the sqlalchemy docs they say: **setuptools is not supported on Python 3 at the time of this writing**. So easy_install could not work.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, don't use `easy_install`. `pip` is much more reliable.

Try installing it and see how things go: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Then, just install your package (search for `cmd` in the Search Bar on the Start Menu and *run it as an Administrator*):

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Comment: thanks @Blender 
for those who are unclear, you'll want to enter this in the Windows Command prompt